# Filling in missing values by conditional grouping based on the number of elements post grouping

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

So my dataset is of this type, where there a few missing values in the ZIP column. Mentioning the columns below:

```
d = {'BLOCK': [1, 1,2,2,3], 'ZIP': [10004, 10003, 10004, 10002, 10004], 'TAXCLASS': [1,2,2,1,1], 'B': [1,1,2,3,1]}
zipBlock = pd.DataFrame(data=d) 
zipBlock

    BLOCK   ZIP TAXCLASS    B
0   1   10004   1   1
1   1   10003   2   1
2   2   10004   2   2
3   2   10002   1   3
4   3   10004   1   1
```

There are 100000 such entries and the df is just for reference.

I want to group by the corresponding B, BLOCK and TAXCLASS, find the number of occurrences of various zips in this grouping and then fill  the missing ZIP with the most common value inside each grouping. However, if the number of elements after the grouping are less than <20,  want to see the most common value only inside the B and TAXCLASS grouping.

This is what I tried doing:

```
from collections import Counter
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def Most_Common(lst):
    data = Counter(lst)
    return data.most_common(1)[0][0]

zipBlock['ZIP5']= np.where(zipBlock.groupby(["B", "BLOCK", "TAXCLASS"])
['ZIP'].size() > 20,\

zipBlock.groupby(["B","BLOCK", "TAXCLASS"])["ZIP"].\
transform(lambda x: x.fillna(Most_Common(x))),
zipBlock.groupby(["B", "TAXCLASS"])["ZIP"].\
transform(lambda x: x.fillna(Most_Common(x))))
```

This is the error I get:

ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes 
Can you please help?

Comment: Please at least ensure that the code you provide can be copied and run.

Comment: My bad, the df I made was just for reference and the code is something that is giving me an error. I need help on understanding how can I fill in the value based on a 'conditional group'. Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Can you fix it please?

Comment: tried giving a better idea of the dataframe. there are 100000 such entries. The transform function by itself without the np.where() works properly but then I can't get the condition to do otherwise where the group has <20 elements.